# Get Table Row Data as String Along With Column Names

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I want to get table row data as single string along with column names (using SQL Server).

Suppose my table structure is:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 LeaveTypeID     |  LeaveTypeName   |   Status   |  DisplayOrder
--------------------------------------------------------------------    
  1                   Earned Leaves      e            1 
  2                   Medical Leave      e            2 
  3                   Casual Leave       e            3
```

Now eg. I want to get the details corresponding to `LeaveTypeID=1`

Then I want the output in the format:

```
LeaveTypeID:1 & LeaveTypeName :Earned Leaves & Status :e & DisplayOrder:1
```

It means output string format should be:

```
FirstColumnName:FirstColumnValue SomeSeparator SecondColumnName:SecondColumnValue SomeSeparator......`
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

`DECLARE @ SomeSeparator VARCHAR(2) = '&'`

```
SELECT 'LeaveTypeID :'
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LeaveTypeID) + ' '
       + @SomeSeparator + ' LeaveTypeName :'
       + LeaveTypeName + ' ' + @SomeSeparator
       + ' Status :' + [status] + ' ' + @SomeSeparator
       + ' DisplayOrder :'
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DisplayOrder)
FROM   <tablename>
WHERE  LeaveTypeID = 1
```

**Update :** To work Dynamically

```
CREATE TABLE testing
  (
     LeaveTypeID   INT,
     LeaveTypeName VARCHAR(50),
     Status        CHAR(1),
     DisplayOrder  INT,
     images        IMAGE
  )

INSERT testing
VALUES (4,'Casual Leave','e',3,NULL),
       (1,'Earned Leaves','e',1,'sdfxfgfg'),
       (2,'Medical Leave','e',2,'dgbdxg' ),
       (3,'Casual Leave','e',3,'rtxtb')

DECLARE @sql           NVARCHAR(max),
        @query         VARCHAR(max)='',
        @SomeSeparator VARCHAR(2) = '&',-- SomeSeparator
        @tablename     VARCHAR(50) ='testing',-- Tablename
        @LeaveTypeID   INT =4 --filter

SET @sql ='Select '

SELECT @query += '+'' ' + @SomeSeparator + ' ' + column_name
                 + ' : ''+' + CASE WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS NULL THEN ' isnull(convert(varchar(30),'+ COLUMN_NAME+'),'''') '
                                   WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS NOT NULL AND DATA_TYPE = 'Image' 
                                   THEN ' isnull(convert(varchar(8000), convert(varbinary(8000),'+ COLUMN_NAME+')),'''') ' 
                                   ELSE ' isnull('+COLUMN_NAME+','''')' END
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = @tablename

SELECT @query = '''' + RIGHT(@query, Len(@query)-3)

SET @sql +=@query + ' from ' + @tablename
           + ' where LeaveTypeID='
           + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @LeaveTypeID) + ''

--PRINT @sql

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Thanks..but here the no of columns can be different..they cannot be static

Comment: @user3879765 - So how the select query is framed. Can you have the column names in variables.

Comment: Firstly I have to get All the Columnn Names of Table And Then Select Their Values And Generate OutPut In above Prescribed Format

Comment: @user3879765 - Are you allowed to use `Dynamic SQL`

Comment: @user3879765 - Check now

Comment: @NoDisplayName-Thanks for your effort.It shows error in case we have `image` datatype as column datatype..How it can be resolved?

Comment: Now ..its outout is null..although there is record in the table...AND some fields are nullable

Comment: It is not going to work ..if any of field have a `NULL` value

Answer (score 0):

LeaveTypeID:1 & LeaveTypeName :Earned Leaves & Status :e & DisplayOrder:1

```
select "LeaveTypeID:"||LeaveTypeID ||" & LeaveTypeName :"||LeaveTypeName ||" & Status :"||Status ||" & DisplayOrder:"||DisplayOrder from table;
```